# Mysql LODA DATA INFILE statement fails to format dates

Tags: mysql, date, load

Mysql can read CSV files using LOAD DATA INFILE as long as the file is in its predefined location.  This seems to work ok, except when it comes to dates.  If I remove the dates, I can load the data.  However, I have a fair amount of data and don't want to remove the dates.  So, after doing a lot of digging and testing, I have the following DML statement that throws the error shown below.  The problem is the Date.  The statement uses DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE( @dob, '%m/%d/%Y'), %Y-%m-%d') to read a string and format it as a DATE.  The table into which the value will be deposited has 2 DATE fields (not DATETIME).

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/subjects_subject.csv' 
INTO TABLE  subjects_subject 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS  
(id,assigned_id,first_name,last_name,middle_name,dob,MRN,Gender,active,institution_id,dod) 
set dob = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(@dob, '%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d');
```

> ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '10/10/1996' for column 'dob' at row 1

The data look like this (with masks for certain items):

```
0,TEST00003,Firstname,Lastname,NULL,6/4/2004,#######,F,1,1,NULL
```

If I remove the dates, the load succeeds.  When I UPDATE the date fields afterward using the same DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE( ...)) syntax, the updates succeed.  However, together, the load fails.

As far as I can tell the syntax is correct.  (If not, please indicate where it's not.)  It seems to me that the functions are not functioning when they should be, ie the date 6/4/2004 should be reformated by STR_TO_DATE as '2004-06-04' and the DATE_FORMAT function should read it and use it as a date.  Neither seems to be happening in the LOAD DATA statement.  (Note: I tried this without DATE_FORMAT as well; same result.)

Can anyone comment or suggest corrections that would help with loading data in mysql?

Thanks,
Joe White

Comment: What is the datatype of `dob`? If it's `DATE` you don't need `DATE_FORMAT()`.

Comment: You're missing `@dob` in the field list.

Comment: `middle_name,dob` should be `middle_name,@dob`